# Set proxy on login if proxy server is reachable

Tags: linux, proxy, environment-variables, kde

I have to move between work, where we have a firewall and have to connect to the internet through a proxy and home where I do not need a proxy.

Since there are no global proxy settings in Linux and a lot of programs just inherit the environment variable `$http_proxy` from the respective parent process, I need to set the environment variables at login. Right now I added these lines in the `~/.profile` file (actually since I'm using KDE I wrote a file at `~/.config/plasma-workspace/env/proxy.sh` which gets sourced at startup by KDE instead of `.profile`):

```
PROXY="some.proxy:22"
# http in lower and upper case variants
export http_proxy=$PROXY
export HTTP_proxy=$PROXY
export HTTP_PROXY=$PROXY

# https
export https_proxy=$PROXY
export HTTPS_proxy=$PROXY
export HTTPS_PROXY=$PROXY
```

With this, the environment variables are visible to all programs and if I open a new shell, they are there. However, if I want to connect without proxy, I have to remove the file or comment out all the lines, log out and log in again.

I tried to write a startup script that tries if the proxy is reachable (using netcat), and in that case exports the https environment variables.

```
server="100.100.100.100"
PROXY="some.proxy:22"
export test="TEST2"
export test2=$(which nc)

nc -w 2 -z 100.100.100.100 22 -v > ~/Desktop/test.txt 2>&1

if nc -w 9 -z $server 22 2>/dev/null; then

    # http in lower and upper case variants
    export http_proxy=$PROXY
    export HTTP_proxy=$PROXY
    export HTTP_PROXY=$PROXY

    # https
    export https_proxy=$PROXY
    export HTTPS_proxy=$PROXY
    export HTTPS_PROXY=$PROXY

fi
```

Now, if I source this script from a terminal `. ./proxy.sh` the environment variables get exported (only for the current terminal and not globally). But this doesn't work at login, because nc fails. The `test.txt` files contains:

```
100.100.100.100: inverse host lookup failed: Host name lookup failure
(UNKNOWN) [100.100.100.100] 22 (http-alt) : Network is unreachable
```

Any suggestion? Is there an alternative way to check if the proxy server is reachable and then set it as an environment variable for all subsequent processes?